# How should I connect the external crystal in MPU6050

Tags: schematics, crystal

[Datasheet for the MPU6050](https://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf)

I am having an external crystal of 32.768 Khz and I want to connect it to the IC,but as given in the IC's block diagram on page 24, I have a CLKIN and CLKOUT on the pin 1 and 22 respectively. But as given in the Pinout as well as in the typical operating curcuit, it is said that the pin 22 is RESV and in description it says "Reserved. Do not connect".

I am unable to figure how the crystal needs to be connected. Should I connect one leg of the crystal to the GND or VCC?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As far as the data sheet is concerned if you want to use the *optional* external reference you would need to inject a signal, not provide a crystal.  It's possible that the mention of clkout on that one drawing indicates there was a design intent to provide an oscillator (or maybe there was one on a related chip, or in some author's misimagination) but the data sheet implies that functionality is either not there, or not officially functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a clock not a crystal eg: from an oscillator like ASEK-32.768KHZ-LRT

Comment: This is correct, at least as far as the data sheet goes.  While using an external frequency source is fully optional, if one is to be used the data sheet implies that it must be a clock oscillator, not a crystal for an on-chip oscillator.